# Splitting a specific bunch of text - JAVA

Tags: java

If I have this element:

```
    <Comments type="ITEM_OUT_COMMENTS" xml:lang="en">Item text
 203871: ATAG ZON POMPUPR 15-60 DO NOT DELETE SupplierAuxiliaryPartID : 395@@!817@@!N

Material PO text

Computers, Mainframe
COMPUTERS,MAINFRAME,SOURCED

                </Comments>
```

Is it also possible to get only this piece of text back: **395@@!817@@!N**

This piece of text is always to be found behind: **SupplierAuxiliaryPartID :** 
But it can happen that there are no spaces like this **SupplierAuxiliaryPartID:395@@!817@@!N**:

```
   <Comments type="ITEM_OUT_COMMENTS" xml:lang="en">Item text
     203871: ATAG ZON POMPUPR 15-60 DO NOT DELETE SupplierAuxiliaryPartID:395@@!817@@!N

    Material PO text

    Computers, Mainframe
    COMPUTERS,MAINFRAME,SOURCED

                    </Comments>
```

I tried several splits but every time I cannot get the right piece of text.

Comment: Try using regex with the Pattern and Matcher classes

Comment: The piece after SupplierAuxiliaryPartID is always different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final String LABEL = "SupplierAuxiliaryPartID"

String getSupplierAuxiliaryPartId(String comments)
{
    // Split comments by line
    for (String line : comments.split('\n'))
    {
        // find where the label is
        int index = line.indexOf(label);

        if (index == -1)
        {
            // no label on this line
            continue;
        }

        // find first colon after the label
        index = line.indexOf(":", index + LABEL.length);

        if (index == -1)
        {
            // label without colon, but maybe the next line has a valid one
            continue;
        }

        // return the remaining of the line after the colon striping out extra whitespaces
        return line.substring(index + 1).trim();
    }

    // label with column not present in comment
    return null;
}
```